# Unity crashed, how can I report that to developers?

Tags: 11.04, unity, compiz, conky

im on ubuntu natty and experiencing some weird random restarts of unity. This started happening after i installed conky and set compiz to remove its shadow. The restarting could possibly be attributed to that.

I did on the otherhand remove ubuntuone and evolution from the default installation too.. but since this didnt start happening before the conky installation, i highly doubt that this is the cause.

So here is the terminal output right before it dies.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/590448/

I need to figure out what could be causing this crash, and the log seems to me like ancient greek... So far, it seems to restart when i click on some unity-aspect of the desktop, like the titlebar, the message-indicator, the lens, or even switching to desktop.

And so, i open the stage up for you guys :D

Answer (score 4):

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

means that the application has done something unexpected, hence the crash.
For that, need to:

1. ensure you are up to date with latest version of the package
2. enable apport (see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport#How to enable apport)
3. ensure /var/crach/*compiz*.crash is cleaned (`rm /var/crach/*compiz*.crash`)
4. wait for it to crash :)
5. shortly then, apport should trigger a dialog with "A crash happened on your system, do you want to report it?". If it's not the case, you can force it to be reported manually: `ubuntu-bug -c /var/crach/*compiz*.crash`.
6. Ensure to choose "report full information" as the light report is not useful for unity.
7. the browser will open a new tab, where you can file additional information like, describing what you were doing during the crash.

Page with more debugging techniques:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/FilingBugs

Answer (score 0):

The bug is probably in Unity. The error report states about some missing compiz files, you can try to reinstall compiz (use synaptic, search for compiz packages and mark for reinstall). I wouldn't worry much about "GLib-GIO-CRITICAL" errors, you get more or less of them in Lucid and Maverick too. The last line of the log shows a Segmentation fault. I recommend you to report a new bug to Launchpad against unity package with

```
ubuntu-bug unity
```

and "Unity crashes with a segmentation fault on loading" or similar as title.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same problem, which lead me to google search "unity crashes when clicking indicator menu", leading me to this. However, just like you, this problem began just after installing conky and using CCSM to make it not add shadows to it using the line (any) & !(class=Conky)

I cannot believe that is a coincidence. I'm going to reset the shadow line and remove conky and see if that stabilizes Unity.