# Unity crashes without any feedback

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity crashed, how can I report that to developers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33846/unity-crashed-how-can-i-report-that-to-developers)

Unity crashes every now and then (but daily). I cannot recognize any pattern of what caused it to crash. After the crash it restarts automatically the desktop. I have a Nvidia Geforce Go 7600.

Is there any log file that could be inspected or reported?

Comment: Even I have the same problem(though my unity does not crash that often).

Comment: It' s not only for Unity, but for Gnome session also. It looks like sudden logout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) let your box soak a day and night in memtest86+

```
  http://www.memtest.org/
```

2) It that reports errors, replace the faulty memory, if not then try another desktop environment. Choice of that is of course very personal but Ubuntu has lots of smoothly working and polished alternatives. For example

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

for the LXDE variant, but there are many other xubuntu-desktop (for xfce), kubuntu-desktop for kde, fluxbox for fluxbox (the last is my favourite)

3) if that still doesn't solve the problem. Maken notes about what you do and try to find a pattern ... if you cannot find a pattern, try another kernel ...

Comment: You don't answer the question at all. Basically you're saying *if you don't like it, leave it* which is for many people not an option.

Comment: Hi Georg, it is generally a good idea to find out what the problem is before acting. Still then as a responsible FOSS user, the best option is to report the bug and not just leave it! (If physical memory is the issue, there are few other options than to abandon it.)